# How to logout user in React using context API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-context

I am working with React hooks and created login logout functionality, but now I want user to logout when token is expired.

- I am on a welcome page and using it, after two minutes if I do something else and the token is expired, I want to logout the user
- I have created a context, Auth context where I have login logout context
- I just want to call the logout function whenever the token expires

**My authContext**

```
  const initialstate = {
  user: null,
};
if (localStorage.getItem("JWT_Token")) {
    const jwt_Token_decoded = Jwt_Decode(localStorage.getItem("JWT_Token"));
    console.log(jwt_Token_decoded.exp * 1000);
    console.log(Date.now());
    if (jwt_Token_decoded.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
        localStorage.clear(); // this runs only when I refresh the page or reload on route change it dosent work
    } else {
        initialstate.user = jwt_Token_decoded;
    }
}

const AuthContext = createContext({
    user: null,
    login: (userData) => {},
    logout: () => {},
});
const AuthReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "LOGIN":
        return {
            ...state,
            user: action.payload,
        };
        case "LOGOUT":
        return {
            ...state,
            user: null,
        };
        default:
        return state;
    }
};
    
const AuthProvider = (props) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, initialstate);
    const login = (userData) => {
        localStorage.setItem("JWT_Token", userData.token);
        dispatch({
        type: "LOGIN",
        payload: userData,
        });
    };
    const logout = () => {
        localStorage.clear();
        dispatch({ action: "LOGOUT" });
    };
    
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{ user: state.user, login, logout }}
        {...props}
        />
    );
};
    
export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

In the above code I am checking for expiry of token, but that only runs when page reloads, here I want to run it in every route change so that I can check for the token expiry.

I don't know how to do that and where to do that.

To logout I just need to call my logout context function, but I don't understand how to make the call.

I don't know If I have to do something in my Axios instance which is a separate file like below. Here I am creating one instance so that I can define my headers and other stuff at one place.

```
//global axios instance
import axios, { AxiosHeaders } from "axios"; // import axios from axios
const BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"; // server api

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "Application/json",
    Access-token: "token here",
  },
});
```

How can I approach this problem? I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997401/how-to-logout-user-when-token-expires-in-react-app) but in this example GraphQL has been used, so there is a function to set context where I can pass and use the `store` to dispatch my logout.

I have shared my axiosInstance code I think something needs to be added there. I am ready to use any approach that will generate some middleware, so that I can check for token in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some points to consider in your approach

1. You can update the log out function to send the user to the login page, this way you guarantee this behavior whenever this user has been logged out;
2. Use the API response to validate when your token has expired, this way you don't need to keep watching the time of the token expiration and logout the user after any unauthorized API call;
3. Pay attention to this `localStorage.clear()` call, sometimes it can clear more than you want, and it is always a good idea to declare what you really want to clear. Eg.: sometimes you want to keep your user language, theme, or some UI configs that shouldn't be cleared after a logout;
4. Axios has an [API to intercept](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) your API call, this is a good way to do something before/after an API call (use it to logout after any unauthorized response)
5. If you really need to take care of this logout by the client and don't need to await the API response, you can try the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) method (not recommended)

Comment: Can you please help me with a example code, like how I asked, I want to know where this interceptor  I should put in my code, as in my axios Instance

Comment: In this Gist you can find one way to solve it
Try to edit it to fit your scenario
https://gist.github.com/yajra/5f5551649b20c8f668aec48549ef5c1f